# How to solve "Invalid Hook Call"?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am learning react-redux, I couldn't understand what problem occuring when I wrap App component with Provider.

> Error: Invalid Hook Call
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFSnF.png

But If I don't wrap it's OK.
Now, My question is what's the mistake in my code?
   **Root Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   import { createStore } from 'redux';

   import App from './components/App';
   import reducers from './reducers';


   const store = createStore(reducers);

   ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
   </Provider>   
   , 
   document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

**App Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import SongList from './songList';

const App = ()=>{
    return (
    <div>
        <SongList />
    </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**SongList Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
class SongList extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className='ui divided list'>
                <div className='ui header'>
                    <div className='title'>
                        Song List
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='ui button primary'>
                    Select
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
export default SongList;
```

**Reducers:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const songReducer = ()=>{
    return [
        {title:'Zikrullah', duration: 4.05},
        {title: 'Madina', duration: 5.50},
        {title: 'Sunnat', duration: 3.96},
        {title: 'Mandatory', duration:5.16}
    ]
};
const selectedSongReducer = (selectedSong = null, action) => {
    if(action.type === 'SONG_SELECTED'){
        return action.payload;
    }
    return selectedSong;
};

export default combineReducers({songs: songReducer, 
                 selectedSong: selectedSongReducer});
```

**Action:**

```
export const selectSong = (song)=> {
 return {
    type: 'SONG_SELECTED',
    payload:song
 };
};
```

I am trying to identify the wrong part of code for two days. I couldn't identify. Please, help me to solve the issue.

Comment: The Song List and Select placeholder is a component? Please create code-sandbox for your issue

Comment: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-songs) stackblitz format is well. Why doesn't work on localhost ? Would you explain please?

Comment: What version of react and react-dom do you have?

Comment: It is 16.12.0 @MateuszKrzyżanowski

Comment: If exactly the same code is working on code-sandbox and is not working locally for me there can be only one issue which is a node_modules directory (remove it and install all again) or sometimes webpack can lose context when you are installing new packages or/and adding new files when it is working.

Comment: @MateuszKrzyżanowski Thanks for giving  your valuable time.